# Create Debian package for a dolphin service menu

Tags: package, debian, rules, debhelper

hi there i have a problem to generate a debian package

i have 2 files to install 1 is a BASH SCRIPT
the other is .DESKTOP FILE

```
/kate-folder-service-menu-0.1.0$ tree
.
└── usr
    ├── bin
    │   └── ktexeditor-open-folder
    └── share
        └── kde4
            └── services
                └── ServiceMenus
                      └── kate-folder.desktop
```

Now i have created all the stuff, with

dh_make -s -c gpl

i have edited:

-control file 
-copyright file
-rules file

in the rules file i have made :

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

# %:
#   dh $@ --with-lzma

# -*- makefile -*-

# Uncomment this to turn on verbose mode.
export DH_VERBOSE=1

configure: configure-stamp
configure-stamp:
    dh_testdir
    touch configure-stamp


build: build-stamp

build-stamp: configure-stamp 
    dh_testdir
    touch $@

clean:
    dh_testdir
    dh_testroot
    rm -f build-stamp configure-stamp
    dh_clean 

install: build
    dh_testdir
    dh_testroot
    dh_clean -k 
    dh_installdirs

binary-indep: build install

binary-arch: build install
    dh_testdir
    dh_testroot
    dh_installchangelogs 
    dh_installdocs
    dh_installexamples
    dh_installman
    dh_link
    dh_strip
    dh_compress
    dh_fixperms
    dh_installdeb
    dh_shlibdeps
    dh_gencontrol


    install --mode=777 -t debian/usr/bin usr/bin/ktexeditor-open-folder
    install --mode=644 -t debian/usr/share/kde4/services/ServiceMenus usr/share/kde4/services/ServiceMenus/kate-folder.desktop

    dh_md5sums
    dh_builddeb

binary: binary-indep binary-arch
.PHONY: build clean binary-indep binary-arch binary install configure
```

now i did

```
debuild -uc -us --source-option=--include-binaries --source-option=-isession
```

and finally this

```
sudo pbuilder build MYSTUFF.dsc
```

but this bastard generates the debian package without the script and the service menu :D

```
dpkg --contents kate-folder-service-menu_0.1.0-1_i386.deb 

drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2012-04-14 14:53 ./
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2012-04-14 14:53 ./usr/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2012-04-14 14:53 ./usr/share/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2012-04-14 14:53 ./usr/share/doc/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2012-04-14 14:53 ./usr/share/doc/kate-folder-service-menu/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       201 2012-04-12 11:16 ./usr/share/doc/kate-folder-service-menu/README.Debian
-rw-r--r-- root/root      1239 2012-04-12 15:31 ./usr/share/doc/kate-folder-service-menu/copyright
-rw-r--r-- root/root       152 2012-04-12 15:55 ./usr/share/doc/kate-folder-service-menu/changelog.Debian.gz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That must be an ancient `dh_make` if it's giving you old-style debhelper rules.

I suggest a modern minimal `debian/rules`:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
%:
        dh $@
```

Then put this in `debian/install`:

```
usr/bin/ktexeditor-open-folder
usr/share/kde4/services/ServiceMenus/kate-folder.desktop
```

That'll use `dh_install` to put them in the right place, and do all the other usual stuff to generate the package.